# Open another view using UINavigationController in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new in iOS development. I want move from one view to another view using UINavigationController. Please tell me if it possible or not, if possible than How??

Comment: Of course it's possible... what do you want use, storyboard ? Xib ? only code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following code :

```
SecondVC *detailView = [[SecondVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
 [detailView release];
```

Comment: Thnaks you!! it's working. and thank you to stackoverflow team such kind of site it's really informative site. 5star bro..!!!

Comment: Please tell me, How to accept anwser..!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Following way :

**.h file**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
```

**.m file**

```
 - (IBAction)gotoSecondView:(id) sender
    {
        NSLog(@"I am going to Second View");
        SecondViewController *SecondView = [[SecondViewController  alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:SecondView animated:YES];

     [SecondView release];
    }
```

For storyboard :

```
SecondViewController* SecondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
[self presentModalViewController:SecondView animated:YES];
```